# WPF Horizontal alignement stretch but cannot set Window width to 100%

Tags: wpf

I have a simple Window that i would like to have a 100% width. I tried the "Stretch" property for Horizontal alignement but width is still stuck to 768.

```
<Window x:Class="WPF.View.MetroMsgBox"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MetroMsgBox" ShowInTaskbar="True"
        WindowStyle="None" ResizeMode="NoResize" 
        FontFamily="Segoe UI" Background="{x:Null}"
        AllowsTransparency="True" 
        Height="135"  WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"
        Deactivated="MetroMsgBox_OnDeactivated" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" >
```

Comment: The `Width` property of any `FrameworkElement` is the width of the element in pixels.  It will never be "100%".  Setting the `HorizontalAlignment` property to `Stretch` means "fill all of the space allotted to you by your parent container".  But the `Width` property will still be a value in pixels.  Note that this applies to any WPF UI control, not just to the `Window` class.

Answer (score 1):

Hi could you just try that :

## Xaml

```
<Window x:Class="WPF.View.MetroMsgBox"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MetroMsgBox" ShowInTaskbar="True"
        Name=_window
        WindowStyle="None" ResizeMode="NoResize" 
        FontFamily="Segoe UI" Background="{x:Null}"
        AllowsTransparency="True" 
        Height="135"  WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"
        Deactivated="MetroMsgBox_OnDeactivated" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" >
```

## Code Behind

```
InitializeComponent();
_window.Width = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width;
```

Comment: It worked , thanks a lot. I had 2 constructors for my Window so it was a bit confusing.

Comment: Ok can you check it as response for your question